# Too many arguments, too few arguments in function pointer

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I'm trying to learn c++ from the basics, and I was playing around with function pointers. Considering this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

bool print(std::string);
bool print(std::string a) 
{
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return true;
}

bool call_user_function(bool(std::string), std::vector<std::string>);
bool call_user_function(bool(*p)(std::string), std::vector<std::string> args) {
    if (args.size() == 0)
        return (*p)();                    (*)
    else if (args.size() == 1)
        return (*p)(args[0]);
    else if (args.size() == 2)
        return (*p)(args[0], args[1]);    (**)
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    std::vector<std::string> a;
    a[0] = "test";
    call_user_function(print, a);
    // ok
    return 0;
}
```

It gives me:

> main.cpp:28 (*): error: too few arguments to function
>
> main.cpp:32 (**): error: too many arguments to function

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `a[0] = "test"` is wrong, because the vector contains no elements. That would work if it contained at least one.

Comment: Though unrelated, the function declaration immediately preceding the definition accomplishes nothing.

Comment: @GManNickG, oh, should I use `push_back()`?

Comment: @JerryCoffin, aren't you forced to define a prototype for every function?

Comment: @Jeffrey, That's more of a useless, standalone compiler (GCC) warning (`-Wmissing-declaration`) in this case, where it's a small, one-file program.

Comment: @chris, I know I should put them into an header file, but for sake of simplicity I've put it there. It's not a project, it's just a test :). But thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Jeffrey: A function definition also acts as a function declaration ("prototype" is really a C term that doesn't apply to C++).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p` is of type `bool(*)(std::string)`.  This means it is a pointer to a function that has a single parameter of type `std::string` and returns a `bool`.

`p` can point to `print`, because the type of `print` matches:  it is a function that has a single parameter of type `std::string` and returns a `bool`.

Your first erroneous expression, `(*p)()`, attempts to call `p` with no arguments.  Your second erroneous expression, `(*p)(args[0], args[1])` attempts to call `p` with two arguments.

The number of arguments must match the number of parameters, so both of these are ill-formed, just like an attempt to call `print` directly with no arguments or with two arguments would result in a compilation error.

Comment: Oh right. Silly me. Is there a way to make it so it's a pointer that return a bool but can have multiple arguments?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do:  `print` only accepts a single argument.  What would it mean to `print` multiple arguments; what do you expect the behavior to be?  One option would be to have your `call_user_function` _apply_ the user function to each of the arguments:  call the user function once for each individual argument.

Comment: I'd like to simulate the PHP behavior of `call_user_function` which can call any function and pass any parameters to it. So I'd like to be able to create my `call_user_function()` that can call any function that returns a bool and has `std::string` as parameters (and you can pass them via the vector).

Comment: It would be a good idea to take a step back and consider:  what are you trying to accomplish?  You say in your question that "I'm trying to learn C++ from the basics."  This isn't something that is usually done in C++:  dynamic invocation of arbitrary functions with arbitrary sets of arguments provided at runtime is not commonly required.  Is there a specific problem you are trying to solve?  If so, there is probably a better solution to that specific problem.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right. As I said I was just playing around. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

@JamesMcNellis has already addressed the problem with the code.

To make something like this work, you probably want to do something like:

```
bool call_user_function(bool(*p)(std::string), std::vector<std::string> args) {
    bool ret = true;
    for (int i=0; i<args.size(); i++)
         ret &= p(args[i]);
    return ret;
}
```

...or, you could use std::for_each (and since you're not using it anyway, I'll ignore the return value for the moment):

```
// avoid copying vector by passing reference to const vector.
void call_user_function(bool (*p)(std::string), std::vector<std::string> const &args) {
    std::for_each(args.begin(), args.end(), p);
}
```

...but, since you're just printing out the contents of the vector, what you should probably use is something more like this:

```
std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), 
          std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Also note that your `a[0] = "test";` is invalid. You want `a.push_back("test");` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`print` has no overload for a call with no arguments.

`print` also doesn't have an overload for two `std::string` arguments.