# C++: Set function pointer to function with fewer/different arguments

Tags: c++, function, pointers, casting

is there a way to set a function pointer with two arguments to functions with fewer or different arguments.

Let's say I have

`double func1(double x);`

and I want a function pointer

`double (*f)(double x, void *void_ptr)`

Setting f=func1; is wrong. So is it possible to cast somehow?

Furthermore, is it possible to cast functions like

`double calc(double x, const XYZ *xyz)`

to achieve f=calc;?

I already tried f=func1; and static_casts. The compiler always says that a conversion is not possible.

Comment: What is the actual problem? Why do you want to use mismatching types?

Comment: You can't do that. (Well, you can *cast*, but it is undefined to call the function through the converted pointer.) Please read about the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: If you've to use cast(to unrelated types), it's an indication that you've a bad design or one haven't thought it through. Specially when there are other options available like `std::function`. Also see [Too many arguments, too few arguments in function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659991/too-many-arguments-too-few-arguments-in-function-pointer)

Comment: As a possible workaround, use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). As in `std::function<double(double, void*)> f;` and `f = [](double x, void*) { return f(x); };`

Comment: On a different note, anytime you feel the need to use a `void*` pointer is a probable sign that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: f should be a pointer (of the mentioned type) to different functions (program run 1: it's set to func1, later func2, ...). f will be used in another function to calculcate these functions in f.

Comment: But *why*? What is this "another function"? Please ask about the actual and underlying problem directly. And read the link provided by @molbdnilo.

Comment: And please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read about [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: Some of these functions have additional data and some don't have any, that explains the void*

Comment: Please provide some example code showing how you would like to use these mismatched function pointers.  We need a use-case.

Comment: @user23325518 Ah but this is C++, we in general don't do `void*` we use variadic templates or other typesafe constructs (like std::variant). So again maybe you better explain WHAT you try to do instead of coming up with this incorrect way of how you want to solve it. Do you need to call a legacy "C" API or something?

Comment: Two things. First, despite the mentions in comments, `void*` is not guaranteed to be able to hold a pointer to function; it points to **data**. Second, even if you can store the pointer that way, you have to convert it back to its original type in order to call it.

Answer (score 3):

A function pointer

> ```
> double (*f)(double x, void *void_ptr)
> ```

points to a function with two arguments, not to a function of different signature. Though, casting is not the issue here. You can cast a pointer to `double func1(double x);` to the above function pointer type, but the resulting pointer is useless, you cannot use it to call the function.

Conceptually it is similar to ordinary pointers. In a nutshell, a pointer to object of certain type is of little use if you don't have an object of that type but an object of different type (aliasing via `char*` et al aside).

You can write the function with desired signature and then get a pointer to it :

```
 double foo(double x,void*) { return func1(x); }

 using fun_type = double(*)(double,void*);
 fun_type f = &foo;
```

However, as you are requsting something like this, indicates that bare function pointers is the wrong tool to begin with. Lambda expressions and `std::function` are much easier to work with when wrapping callables or binding arguments. Perhaps you actually need just a callable with right signature, ie nothing more complicated than:

```
 auto f = [](double x,void*) { return func1(x); };
```